# okta laravel vue development getting save error from ubuntu terminal

Tags: laravel, vue.js, yarnpkg, okta-api

I am doing a tutorial using laravel and vuew and okta.
[From](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/01/15/crud-app-laravel-vue) here but when I run the command

```
yarn add --save vue-router axios @okta/okta-vue
```

It gives me the error

```
Usage: yarn [options]

yarn: error: no such option: --save
```

UPDATE:

install

```
npm install --save axios vue-axios
yarn add vue-router axios @okta/okta-vue
```

Still did not solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you use

```
npm add --save vue-router axios kta/okta-vue
npm run serve
```

it works！